# How to set different constraints in a Splash depending on the iPhone size?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, constraints, splash-screen

I'm working on a project where one of the requirements is, that the company logo must appear at 10% distance from the top of the iPhone's screen size (if it's an iPhone 5, 568 height, it should be at 57). I can apply a constraint, but as far as I know, it's a fix value and not relative.
I have been checking the "Vary for traits" feature of Xcode, but since all of the sizes I need are wC hR, it's not working in this case.
Another solution would be to apply different splashes depending on the iPhone model, but I'm not sure it's possible.

Any ideas about it? Thx!

Comment: Use an aspect ratio constraint. Can you clarify; should themlogo width be 10% of screen width or should the space to the left of the logo be 10% of the screen width?

Comment: It's a vertical space constraint, I think I can only apply fix values to that. Is there any way to make it relative?

Comment: The trick is to put a placeholder transparent `UIView` beside the logo and constrain the height of that view to 1/10th of the height of the screen and constrain the logo's top edge to the placeholder's bottom edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a placeholder view to create the vertical space you need.

Add a `UIView` above the logo:

[image]

Constrain the top of this view to the top of the root view
Constrain the bottom of this view to the top of the logo
Constrain the height of this view to 1/10 of the height of the root view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that in code as well.

```
logoImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// This will keep your imageView 10% from the top
NSLayoutConstraint(item: logoImageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .topMargin, multiplier: 1.0, constant: self.view.frame.size.height/10).isActive = true

// Additional You will want your imageView to be centered.
NSLayoutConstraint(item: logoImageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: As it's in the splash, I can't code. That was the main problem